# LocalSessionFactoryBean does not return a SessionFactory instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following standard configuration:

```
<bean id="globalSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"></ref>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>...</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And in another module:

```
<bean id="configurationSettingsService" class="com.HibernateConfigurationSettingsService">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="globalSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Class using session factory:

```
public class HibernateConfigurationSettingsService implements ConfigurationSettingsService {

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```

Only versions of libs on classpath are:

hibernate 3.5.4-Final
spring    3.2.3.RELEASE

Trying to run the application in Tomee (using tomcat 7), get the following error:

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of ty
pe 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean' to required type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' for property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] to required type [org.hibernate.S
essionFactory] for property 'sessionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Anyone have any idea why is Spring not retuning an instance of SessionFactory here?

Thanks all.

Resolved! Problem was with having spring libs on two classpaths, as soon as I set individual module dependencies to provided, everything was fine.